# First Jinja not running

Tags: python, jinja2

I am running a Python Jinja template file for the first time, but by looking online I am not finding a clear example.

Below is my code, `first.py` is my Python app and the template output is `home.html`

Here is an [error log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Io65.png)

```py
    from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape
    env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('first.py', 'templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
    template = env.get_template('home.html')
    print template.render(the='variables', go='here')
```

What am I missing for it to run? What variable should be inside the render?

Comment: What is the error log ?

Comment: I have added above the image for error log

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the parenthesis on line 3

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('first.py', 'templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml']))  # <- you forgot ) here
template = env.get_template('home.html')
print template.render(the='variables', go='here')
```

To avoid this kind of obvious errors use proper IDE. For example [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows), it has error checking capabilities.

Comment: Am still facing the same error, i have no idea what might be the problem